# Copy files from one directory to another and append new files with timestamp instead of overwriting in Java

Tags: java, timestamp, copy

I want to copy files from source directory to destination. If the file already exists in the destination directory, then append the new file to be copied with its timestamp so that there is no overwrite. How do I check for duplicates and append timestamp to the new file name? Please help!

```
public static void copyFolder(File src, File dest)
    throws IOException{
        //list all the directory contents
        String files[] = src.list();
        for (String file : files) {
           //construct the src and dest file structure
           File srcFile = new File(src, file);
           File destFile = new File(dest, file);
           //recursive copy
           copyFolder(srcFile,destFile);
        }
    }else{
        //if file, then copy it
        //Use bytes stream to support all file types
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(src);
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dest);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
            //copy the file content in bytes
            while ((length = in.read(buffer)) > 0){
               out.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }

            in.close();
            out.close();
            System.out.println("File copied from " + src + " to " + dest);
    }
}
```

Comment: What if there is still "overwrite" after appending the file name?

Comment: And what's the current behavior (problem) with your code?

Comment: @user202729 I’m afraid the problem is that it doesn’t compile. But I’m also afraid that this wasn’t the question.

Comment: What did your search and research bring up? In what way was it insufficient? In any case I suggest you append `Instant.now().toString()` to your file name in order for it to contain a timestamp. If you get stuck trying that, please ask a new and more specific question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    //construct the src and dest file structure
    File srcFile = new File(src, file);
    File destFile = new File(dest, file);
    while (destFile.exists()) {
        destFile = new File(dest, file + '-' + Instant.now());
    }
```

In one case the destination file got named `test-file.txt-2018-03-14T11:05:21.103706Z`. The time given is in UTC. In any case you will end up with a name of file that doesn’t already exist (if the loop terminates, but I have a hard time seeing the scenario where it doesn’t).

You may want to append the timestamp only to plain files and reuse existing folders (directories), I don’t know your requirements here. And you may want to append the timestamp before the extension if there is one (to get `test-file-2018-03-14T11:05:21.103706Z.txt` instead). I trust you to make the necessary modifications.

Comment: Ole! I get this error - "Java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\givret\Desktop\Dest1\file-2018-03-17T01:06:07.151Z (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)" when I add the snippet that you gave as a solution. But the file exists!

Comment: Sorry, colons are not allowed in Windows file names, I believe this is why. It’s years ago since I used Windows. You may try something like `Instant.now().toString().replace(':', '.')`.

Comment: Thanks Ole. It worked when I removed the colons and when I used file.getName().

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the file exists using File.exist() method, if exists, you can open the file in the append mode

The code is something like this

```
File f = new File(oldName);
if(f.exists() && !f.isDirectory()) { 
    long currentTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
    String newName=oldName+currentTime;
    // do the copy

}
```

Comment: OP isn't asking about appending the **contents** of the source file to any same-named destination file; he wants to know how to find out if a same-named file already exists in the destination and, if so,**give the copy a  different name** by appending a timestamp to the name of the existing file.